# I can't get an instance of Ext.MessageBox in a viewController

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.define('mondernTunes.view.main.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'mainview',
    controller: 'MyMainViewController',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'mainviewmodel'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'component',
        html: '<a style="font-size:24px" target="_blank" href="https://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0-CE/guides/quick_start/What_You_Will_Be_Coding.html">Quick Start Tutorial Here</a><p>'
    }, {
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        reference: 'df',
        bind: {
            value: 'clickTime'
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Click Me!',
        handler: 'onButtonClick'
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: "say hello",
        handler: "sayHello" //  will call sayHello in viewController
    }]
})
```

---

```
Ext.define('mondernTunes.view.main.MyMainViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.MyMainViewController',
    requires: ['Ext.MessageBox'],

    sayHello: function (button) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert("hello");
    }
})
```

**Question:**
The console gives me a error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Ext.MessageBox.alert is not a function
```

How can i get a instance of `Ext.MessageBox` in `viewController`?

Comment: how can i get an instance of Ext.MessageBox in the ViewController

Comment: Can you reproduce this inside a fiddle? Could you please add the ExtJS version number.

Comment: This is not a solution, but some best practice: 1) Please capitalise the app name: ModernTunes, 2) keep the alias lower case, if you have add '-': my-mainviewcontroller 3) stick to a single name for view, viewModel and viewController xtype and alias: 'mainview'

Answer (score 0):

Try *Ext.Msg.alert("hello");* instead of *Ext.MessageBox.alert("hello");*